# How to make onBindViewHolder allow lists of different object types in a single adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make that android RecyclerView.Adapter allows lists of different object types in a single adapter.
There are two data DTOs : product and post.
How to paginate when multiple View Types are involved?
When I make like below, It gets error "Product product = getItem(position);".
I don't want to inheritance in my DTOs.

[image]

**PostsRecyclerAdapter.class**

```
 public class PostsRecyclerAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Post, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int LAYOUT_DETAIL_PRODUCT = 0;
    private static final int LAYOUT_POSTS = 1;

                               ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case LAYOUT_DETAIL_PRODUCT:
                Product product = getItem(position); **=> get error!**
                DetailProductViewHolder detailProductViewHolder = (DetailProductViewHolder) holder;
                detailProductViewHolder.detailProductName.setText(product.getPrTitle());
                detailProductViewHolder.detailProductRating.setText(Integer.toString(product.getPrScore()));
                loadingPicture(product.getPrImage()).into(detailProductViewHolder.detailProductImage);
                break;

            case LAYOUT_POSTS:
                Post post = getItem(position);
                PostsViewHolder postsViewHolder = (PostsViewHolder) holder;
                postsViewHolder.postGoodPoint.setText(post.getGoodContents());
                postsViewHolder.postBadPoint.setText(post.getBadContents());
                loadingPicture(post.getPrImage()).into(postsViewHolder.postPicture);
                break;   
        }
    }
```

**post.class**

```
      public class Post {
          @SerializedName("id")
          private Integer id;
          @SerializedName("title")
          private String title;
          @SerializedName("score")
          private Integer score;     
          private String storedPath;
          @SerializedName("good_contents")
          private String goodContents;
          @SerializedName("bad_contents")
          private String badContents;
          @SerializedName("pr_id")
          private Integer prId;


   public Integer getId() {
       return id;
  }
   public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   ...
 }
```

**Product.class**

```
public class Product {
    @SerializedName("pr_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer prId;
    @SerializedName("pr_title")
    @Expose
    private String prTitle;
    @SerializedName("pr_score")
    @Expose
    private Integer prScore;
    @SerializedName("pr_registed_time")
    @Expose
    private String prRegistedTime;
    @SerializedName("pr_image")
    @Expose
    private String prImage;
    @SerializedName("pr_category")
    @Expose
    private Integer prCategory;
    @SerializedName("pr_review_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer prReviewCount;

    public Product(String productPicture, Integer productCategory, String title, int reviewCount, int productScore) {
        prImage = productPicture;
        prCategory = productCategory;
        prTitle = title;
        prReviewCount = checkReviewCount(reviewCount);
        prScore = productScore;
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an empty interface and implement it on Post and Product (let's call it MyInterface) and replace the type on your `PostsRecyclerAdapter` class

```
public class PostsRecyclerAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<MyInterface, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

And in your Adapter you should cast to the appropiate case:

```
Product product = (Product) getItem(position)
.
.
.
Post post = (Post) getItem(position);
```